# Ordering the activation of modules in jess

Tags: jess

I am using JESS to write a program which eliminates some elements in the deftemplate for each rule that is fired.

I want to print out the results to a file after all rules have been fired.
I have put all the rules which effect the deftemplate in a defmodule, and made two seperate modules for reporting the results. but the point is the reporting modules are executed in between and therefore there rules will be fired,
I want to have the report modules executed at the end, 
Can I use the defadvice after halt?
shall I add another rule saying that when all other rules from MAIN module are fired, then (focus Report1 Report2)?

Any assist will be appreciated,

Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put all the changing rules into a named module and

```
(focus Changes Report1 Report2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much,But in this case the modules which I want to run last will also be running while the Changes module is running, I want the Report module to only run once at the end of the process.

Comment: "in this case the modules which I want to run last will also be running while the Changes module is running" **This is wrong.**

Comment: But watching the focus will show that the module has been fired in the middle of the process, which shall not be expected, right?

Comment: Which module, in the middle of which process? Are you reporting facts or surmises?

Comment: I have attached the screen shot of the screen I get, maybe I havent been able to explain the situation correctly. Thank you very much Laune

Comment: Sorry I was unable to attach the file, but What I do mean is at the middle of the screen you can see that after all the modules the Report module has been executed, and then the same modules which had been executed before  the report are executed again, which part am I making a mistake in?

Comment: Sorry - I'm not seeing anything. You'll have to take the time and make an effort to put it all in text and add it to your Q.